# Перенос div после span

Tags: html

Подскажите как сделать так что бы div идущий после span в случае если в span много текста перемещался под span а не уезжал за пределы области.
Спасибо.

```html
<div class="JsConnect-Connect">
  <a class="ConnectLink" href="somelink">
    <img class="ProfilePhotoSmall UserPhoto" src="somelink">
    <span class="Username">imsuperlongnamebringer</span>
    <div class="ConnectLabel TextColor">Войти через чтонибудь</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` уезжает, т.к. это блочный элемент и занимает всю строку, чтобы изменить его поведение, его надо сделать строчным любым из этих способов.

- установить для этого `div` css свойство `display:inline-block`
- установить для этого `div` css свойство `display:inline`
- использовать тег `span` вместо `div`.

```css
.inlineDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inlineBlockDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>inline</h3>
<div class="JsConnect-Connect">
  <a class="ConnectLink" href="somelink">
    <img class="ProfilePhotoSmall UserPhoto" src="somelink">
    <span class="Username">imsuperlongnamebringer</span>
    <div class="inlineDiv ConnectLabel TextColor">Войти через чтонибудь</div>
  </a>
</div>
<h3>inline-block</h3>
<div class="JsConnect-Connect">
  <a class="ConnectLink" href="somelink">
    <img class="ProfilePhotoSmall UserPhoto" src="somelink">
    <span class="Username">imsuperlongnamebringer</span>
    <div class="inlineBlockDiv ConnectLabel TextColor">Войти через чтонибудь</div>
  </a>
</div>

<h3>span</h3>
<div class="JsConnect-Connect">
  <a class="ConnectLink" href="somelink">
    <img class="ProfilePhotoSmall UserPhoto" src="somelink">
    <span class="Username">imsuperlongnamebringer</span>
    <span class="inlineSpan ConnectLabel TextColor">Войти через чтонибудь</span>
  </a>
</div>
```